# Is it possible to levitate an object with piezoelectricity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, piezoelectric

The delay for transmit pressure depend of speed of sound in the material. A lot of piezo slip-stick actuator can generate an asymetric wave. Like the differential pressure is not the same the force to up can cancel gravity ?

In example, with 400 actuators, each actuator give force to down in 1/1000000s enough for cancel gravity while 1/1000000s, wait 10/1000000s and a force to up in (1/400 - 11/1000000)s. But next actuator action at time 1/1000000s. etc.

[image: actuactor]

Comment: Are we talking about [acoustic levitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_levitation)? Sure, this things do exists.

Comment: I'm not sure. There is no external forces (or support) except gravity. Is it possible to levitate without external forces except gravity ?

Answer (score 2):

> Like the differential pressure is not the same the force to up can
>   cancel gravity ?

You cannot cancel gravity, you can simply counteract it with another force.

> Is it possible to levitate an object with piezoelectricity?

Yes. It is possible. But the piezoelectricty part is misleading. Better to say acoustic levitation, because you are using the vibration of the piezo to generate acoustic waves which interact in a medium to COUNTERACT gravity.

See link for a demonstration.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=669AcEBpdsY